# Memory efficient way to add columns to .csv files

Tags: python, csv

Ok, I couldn't really find an answer to this anywhere else, so I figured I'd ask.

I'm working with some .csv files that have about 74 million lines right now and I'm trying to add columns into one file from another file.

ex.

```
Week,Sales Depot,Sales Channel,Route,Client,Product,Units Sold,Sales,Units Returned,Returns,Adjusted Demand
3,1110,7,3301,15766,1212,3,25.14,0,0,3
3,1110,7,3301,15766,1216,4,33.52,0,0,4
```

combined with

```
Units_cat
0
1
```

so that

```
Week,Sales Depot,Sales Channel,Route,Client,Product,Units Sold,Units_cat,Sales,Units Returned,Returns,Adjusted Demand
3,1110,7,3301,15766,1212,3,0,25.14,0,0,3
3,1110,7,3301,15766,1216,4,1,33.52,0,0,4
```

I've been using pandas to read in and output the .csv files, but the issue I'm coming to is the program keeps crashing because creating the DataFrame overloads my memory. I've tried applying the csv library from Python but I'm not sure how merge the files the way I want (not just append).

Anyone know a more memory efficient method of combining these files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this might work for you:

#### Using `csv.DictReader()`

```
import csv
from itertools import izip

with open('file1.csv') as file1:
    with open('file2.csv') as file2:
        with open('result.csv', 'w') as result:
            file1 = csv.DictReader(file1)
            file2 = csv.DictReader(file2)

            # Get the field order correct here:
            fieldnames = file1.fieldnames
            index = fieldnames.index('Units Sold')+1
            fieldnames = fieldnames[:index] + file2.fieldnames + fieldnames[index:]

            result = csv.DictWriter(result, fieldnames)

            def dict_merge(a,b):
                a.update(b)
                return a
            result.writeheader()
            result.writerows(dict_merge(a,b) for a,b in izip(file1, file2))
```

#### Using `csv.reader()`

```
import csv
from itertools import izip

with open('file1.csv') as file1:
    with open('file2.csv') as file2:
        with open('result.csv', 'w') as result:
            file1 = csv.reader(file1)
            file2 = csv.reader(file2)
            result = csv.writer(result)

            result.writerows(a[:7] + b + a[7:] for a,b in izip(file1, file2))
```

Notes:

- This is for Python2. You can use the normal `zip()` function in Python3. If the two files are not of equivalent lengths, consider `itertools.izip_longest()`.
- The memory efficiency comes from passing a generator expression to `.writerows()` instead of a list. This way, only the current line is under consideration at any moment in time, not the entire file. If a generator expression isn't appropriate, you'll get the same benefit from a `for` loop: `for a,b in izip(...): result.writerow(...)`
- The `dict_merge` function is not required starting from Python3.5. In sufficiently new Pythons, try `result.writerows({**a,**b} for a,b in zip(file1, file2))` (See [this explanation](http://treyhunner.com/2016/02/how-to-merge-dictionaries-in-python/)).